# How would I change my camera output to my screen display?

Tags: camera, output, display, capture

As the title states, how would I be able to change my camera output as a screen share for some programs that don't have the screen share option?

Comment: Please ask a more specific question. which software or language are you using

Comment: I am looking for a program that can do this